# Udacity's Sunshine-Version-2 app creating ForecastFragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments

while learning from Udacity´s Sunshine app lesson, immediately after creating the sugested ForecastFragment.java - extracted from MainActivity.java - I got an error on both java fles, regardind the reference to ForecastFragment as shown int the code below.

In MainActivity at "new ForecastFragment()";

In ForecastFragment at "Public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {"

Help will be very much appreciated.

// MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

// ForecastFragment.java

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.android.sunshine.app.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
```

Comment: you are not showing any error

Comment: I don't know how to highlight the errors... but both references to ForecastFragment are underlined in red in Studio

Comment: that is not a complete error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this question. I've just figured out what is the problem: I have to include the reference to the app package at the beginning  of the ForescastFragment.java, i.e, 
    Package com.example.android.sunshine.app;